# Connect MacBook to External Monitor Using USB to HDMI

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018)  and an HP EliteDisplay E243 23.8-inch monitor with a HDMI port.

I have a USB to HDMI cable but when I connect my MacBook Air to my monitor using the USB to HDMI it does not work. Can you please help me?

Comment: Which exact model of MacBook and which monitor? What exactly happens? Is the display listed in About This Mac? What OS version? Please give as much detail and info as possible.

Comment: It is a MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018). It is an HP monitor with a HDMI port. When I use the USB to HDMI port nothing happens. The monitor just says no signal. It does not show up in about this mac. It is mac os Mojave.

Comment: What\s the resolution size of this monitor?

Comment: it is 23 inches

Comment: No, 1080 x 1920, that sort of thing.

Comment: how do i check?

Comment: What is the full name of the monitor, e.g. E243 FHD. Also, are you using the Apple USB to monitor adaptor, https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207806 or something else?

Comment: HP EliteDisplay E243 23.8-inch Monitor. I am using an apple usb to hdmi port.

Answer (score 1):

A 1080 x 1920 display is easily within the capabilities of your MacBook Air. So, there are really only three possible reasons why this isn't working:

**1. The monitor itself doesn't work.**

Is this a brand new display, out of the box? Does it display a 'not connected' or 'no input' symbol on the screen, so that you can see that the screen itself works? Can you test it with another computer?

**2. The MacBook Air doesn't work**

Can you test the MBA with another display? Does the internal display work fine? Have you any reason to suspect that it might not work? Does the port work with other USB devices?

**3. The cable/adaptor doesn't work**

This is by far the most likely explanation, and the cheapest to test. If you have a USB to HDMI adaptor, followed by an HDMI to HDMI cable, try changing the cable first. Then try changing the adaptor.

Comment: Ok, I know that the HDMI to HDMI works because I tested it. Will see about a new adapter and get back to you.